hash from openssl and MySQL for MD5 and SHA256 is different
echo -n 'yourstring' | openssl dgst -md5
MD5(stdin)= 5d7aed02367214a092f9eefed33f86d7

SELECT MD5('yourstring');
0653fc45290cd602be895bb8d054942c


echo -n 'yourdata' | openssl dgst -sha256
SHA2-256(stdin)= 3155c1e53ebf714c6a3a074b3d0547cb8d0d92b0781a2b539a9953cc06e0440c

SELECT SHA2('yourdata', 256);
877d0019ddf00063e6677738ced44f5972e2d9f667121a20c390c84e020d2e10


SELECT @@character_set_database, @@collation_database, version();

'utf8mb4', 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci', '8.4.2'

OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 11 Home
OS Version:                10.0.22631 N/A Build 22631
C:\Users\admin>openssl version
OpenSSL 3.3.1 4 Jun 2024 (Library: OpenSSL 3.3.1 4 Jun 2024)
I expected both hashes to be the same. Tried different variation of converting to HEX and CAST(string AS BINARY) etc.
Tried echo with and without -n and with single and double quotes. The hashes are always different.





I cannot reproduce this problem. I tested both cases you show. Both produce matching hashes from openssl and mysql. I'm using openssl 3.3.2, MySQL Server 8.4.2, MacOS 14.6.1.

The shell behaviour on a gnome Terminal and bash (5.2.26), openssl-3.2.2 I tested to match your SQL results.

I also tried multiple variations using iconv to convert to different character sets that might be in use, such as echo -n 'yourstring' | iconv -t utf16be | openssl dgst -md5.  While not exhaustive, none of the utf16 or utf32 character sets produced the hash values posted here.  You need to add a lot more details to your question, include the OpenSSL version, OS, shell you're using, and and especially all locale settings.

What command shell are you running?  Powershell?  cmd.exe?  Please add the output from chcp.

Code page 65001 is UTF8, so that's almost certainly not the issue given your input data.  Can you add the -d option to the openssl command so it will at least show how many bytes it's reading?  echo -n 'yourstring' | openssl dgst -d -md5.  Also check the output from running, in PowerShell, something like echo -n 'yourdata' | Format-Hex

I ran echo -n 'yourstring'>out.txt in cmd.exe and looked at the file.... it contained -n 'yourstring'[cr][lf]

@velcrow Interesting that echo -n yourdata | Format-Hex in Powershell does not appear to add the [cr][lf].

@velcrow Something else is also going on. printf -- "-n \'yourstring\'\r\n" | openssl dgst -d -md5 on an Ubuntu system returns (stdin)= 9966dafaeb773a173d06b0b5b33438fe, which doesn't match.  I did notice read return 17 in the output.  But OP's result shows read returned 1, processing 16.  Assuming the difference in output is due to a different version of OpenSSL, likely means OP's version of OpenSSL is getting 16 characters to hash.
